# C++ library to read Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: c++, microsoft-excel, visual-studio, spreadsheet

I've got a language phrase translation table in Excel.
I would like to write, in C++, a program that creates C++ source data tables from the Excel Spreadsheet.

Is there are recommended library for this?

I'll be using Visual Studio 2019.
I'm using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13127.21668) 64-bit.

Preference is freeware.
The application I'm writing will be an inhouse tool and not inside any product.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with excel files from C++, specifically, but github appears to have these 3 projects that are each quite popular.

---

[**OpenXLSX**](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX) (The readme specifically metnions that it works with VS 2019 using the cmake extension)

> Many programming languages have the ability to modify Excel files,
> either natively or in the form of open source libraries. This includes
> Python, Java and C#. For C++, however, things are more scattered.
> While there are some libraries, they are generally less mature and
> have a smaller feature set than for other languages.
>
> Because there are no open source library that fully fitted my needs, I
> decided to develop the OpenXLSX library.

---

[**xlnt**](https://tfussell.gitbooks.io/xlnt/content/docs/introduction/Features.html) appears to be the C++ Excel library with the most stars on github. It appears that its **syntax closely matches Excel's** own. Its [**feature list**](https://tfussell.gitbooks.io/xlnt/content/docs/introduction/Features.html) indicates that it supports a standard spreadsheet made up of simple column/row data, but I also see it specifically **does not support "Tables"**, so you might want to double check if this one is going to work for you before diving in.

---

[**readxl**](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl) claims to offer a simplicity which they suggest matches this cheatsheet from **rstudio**:
[image: dataimport1] [image: dataimport2]

---

If you're curious, I found these using a wonderful new(to me) tool [https://www.**awesomeopensource**.com](https://www.awesomeopensource.com) that makes finding the gems hidden within github a breeze with its simple category based listings ranked by stars. I know that sounds like something easily done within github itself, but I implore you to **give it a try** and see the difference!

Answer (score 0):

[Spire.XLS for C++](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/xls-for-CPP.html) library can be used to read Excel files in C++ applications.
You can install the library through NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Spire.XLS.Cpp
```

After installation, you can refer to the following code to read an Excel file:

```
#include "Spire.Xls.o.h";
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

using namespace Spire::Xls;
using namespace Spire::Common;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Create a Workbook instance
    Workbook* workbook = new Workbook();
    //Load an Excel file
    workbook->LoadFromFile(L"Sample1.xlsx");

    //Get the first worksheet
    Worksheet* sheet = workbook->GetWorksheets()->Get(0);

    //Get the cell collection of the worksheet
    IList<XlsRange>* cellCollection = sheet->GetCells();

    //Create a wstring object to append cell values
    wstring buffer = L"";

    //Iterate through all the cells in the collection
    for (int i = 0; i < cellCollection->GetCount(); i++)
    {
        XlsRange* cr = cellCollection->GetItem(i);
        //Get cell addresses and values
        wstring cell = cr->GetRangeAddressLocal();
        wstring result = L"Cell: " + cell + L"   Value: " + cr->GetValue();
        buffer += (result + L"\n");
    }

    //Save to a TXT file
    wofstream write(L"CellValues.txt");
    auto LocUtf8 = locale(locale(""), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
    write.imbue(LocUtf8);
    write << buffer;
    write.close();
    workbook->Dispose();
    delete workbook;
}
```

Note: I work for the company that developed this library.